# Woo Commerce login redirect

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, redirect, custom-wordpress-pages

```
/**
 * Redirect wholesalers to custom page user after successful login.
 *
 * @param string $redirect_to URL to redirect to.
 * @param string $request URL the user is coming from.
 * @param object $user Logged user's data.
 * @return string
 */
```

How can I redirect my customers just after login in (WooCommerce plugin):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wcs_login_redirect');
function wcs_login_redirect( $redirect ) {
    $redirect = 'http://google.com/';
    return $redirect;
}
```

Comment: Mycode is not working wat i will do

Comment: why do you want to redirect your customers to another web site?